# Symfony2 htaccess mod rewrite issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I've been having this issue for quite some time. Right now we are using a shared hosting plan and have four domains, one of which points to a symfony project. My goal is simply to omit having the `app.php` included in the URL. Without any `.htaccess` applied, all domains work flawlessly and when trying to navigate to the symfony domain I simply get a directory listing instead of having the page render, unless I include the `app.php` in the URL.

When applying the below htaccess, all non-symfony related domains show a `500 error` and the one symfony related domain renders successfully, without the `app.php` in the URL. My goal at this point is to modify the `htaccess` so that all non-symfony related domains render successfully as they did before, while still maintaining the below .htacces to omit the `app.php` from the Symfony related project.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

`.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

With :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to be somewhat working. Two of my domains are up (one being non-symfony related), the other two are still down. Previously all but one were down, so slightly better than before :)

Comment: Talked to customer support and they said the other sites are down due to excessive redirects that cannot be completed.

Comment: If you use Apache 2.2.16 or higher, you can use the [FallbackResource directive](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/01/21/apaches-fallbackresource-your-new-htaccess-command/)